# why is Probability (at least one solved) =$P(A \cup B)$

Tags: probability

I have a question in which it is stated that the probability of a student solving a problem A is $\frac{2}{3}$. And the probability of solving another problem B is $\frac{3}{5}$. So what is the probability that he will solve at least one problem?

In the solution they consider the probability of getting at least one problem $P(A\cup B)$ right. Please, can anyone explain why will the probability of at least one problem be that?I know the Venn diagram proof can anyone give THEOROTIC explanation to this?I want to understand it logically and theorotically.

Comment: Note that there are four possible cases here. (1) Student solves both, (2) Student solves only first problem, (3) Student solves only second, (4) Student solves neither. You want the probability that one of (1), (2) or (3) occurs. What is $A \cup B$ here? $A$ is the union of the events (1) and (2) and $B$ is the union of the events (1) and (3). The union of $A$ and $B$ is the events (1), (2), (3).

Comment: A is the first problem and B is the another one

Comment: You should change the heading. $P(A\; or\; B)$ and $P(A\cup B)$  are two ways of denoting the same thing, the probability that $A$ or $B$ or both occur. What you are asking in the body of the question is why $P(A\cup B) = P(\; at\; least\; one\; solved)$

Comment: For a complete explanation of what $P(A\cup B)$ means, first we need to understand how the event $A$ in $P(A)$ can be a _set._ Do you have such a definition of probability? Different authors use slightly different words to describe events as sets, so any explanation of the meaning of $P(A\cup B)$ will work better if it uses the same words your book or instructor used, and it would be helpful to know what they said. But if you have never seen the language of sets used to describe events in probability, we must start from the beginning.

Comment: I know the concepts about sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$
A = \text{solving problem n°1} \\
B = \text{solving problem n°2}
$$

Then the event $\text{solving at least one}$ is the same as solving either problem n°1 or problem n°2 or both :
$$
\text{solving at least one} = A \cup B
$$
By definition the union of two events is the event that represents the occurrence of either A or B or both. This is a definition. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) or [that](http://www.probabilityformula.org/union-of-events.html).

Comment: But why is solving at least one P(AUB).please can you state its reason

Comment: @ATHARVA Because that's what union means.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let $A$ be the event of a student solve problem 1 and $B$ the event of the student solve problem 2. Then the probability of solving at least one problem is the probability of solving problem 1 OR 2 (he can also solve both).

Another way of thinking is that the probability of solving at least one problem is $(1 - $"the probability of solving 0 problem) and the probability of solving 0 problem is the probability of not solving problem 1 AND not solving problem 2.

Answer (score 0):

In the diagram for the union of two sets [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)),

the area in the rectangle represents $\mathbb U$, the set of all possible values,
and the combined area of the two circles represents $A\cup B$

so $1 - \mathbb P(A \cup B)$ means neither occurs,

and $\mathbb P(A\cup B)$ means that at least one of them occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The event "Problem A is solved" gets the name $A$, and the event "Problem B is solved" gets the name $B$. Then the event "At least one problem is solved" can be renamed into "Problem A is solved OR problem B is solved" (remember that in logic and mathe matics, "or" means "either one or both"), which may be shortened (using our names) to "$A$ OR $B$".

Symbolically, that "OR" is what $\cup$ means. Therefore, "$A$ OR $B$" is the same as saying $A \cup B$. Note that this all happens before even mentioning $P$ or probabilities. It's just convensions on putting names on composite events.